# Expanding Apple RAID 5 in terminal

Tags: raid, apple

I own a Mac Pro with an Apple RAID card. I set it up with three 1.5TB drives. I recently replaced one drive with a 3TB drive and now want the volume to expand to meet the new capacity. The Apple manual tells me to type in to terminal

```
$ sudo raidutil modify volume --expand -n volume -s size.
```

I tried several times to do this with different combinations but it wont work. Below is the last time I tried. Any help would be appreciated.

```
NYCretoucher-Remote:~ nisian$ sudo raidutil modify volume --expand -n volume R1V1 -s size 700
Required argument missing: '--size'


usage: raidutil <global-options> modify volume <required-arguments> <optional-arguments>
    global-options:
        [--controller <ControllerType> | -c <ControllerType>]
        [--terse | -t]
        [--verbose | -v]
        [--version | -V]
    --expand | -e
        required arguments:
            --name <VolumeName> | -n <VolumeName>
            --size <SizeToExpandVolume> | -s <SizeToExpandVolume>
        optional arguments:
            --raidset <RAIDSetName> | -r <RAIDSetName>
            --waitfortask | -W
    --move | -m
        required arguments:
            --names <VolumeName> | -n <VolumeName>
            --targetraidset <TargetRAIDSetName> | -t <TargetRAIDSetName>
            --raidset <RAIDSetName> | -r <RAIDSetName>
        optional arguments:
        --waitfortask | -W
    --rewrite | -w
        required arguments:
            --name <VolumeName> | -n <VolumeName>
        optional arguments:
            --priority <ServicePriority> | -p <ServicePriority>
            --raidset <RAIDSetName> | -r <RAIDSetName>
            --waitfortask | -W
    --verify | -v
        required arguments:
            --name <VolumeName> | -n <VolumeName>
        optional arguments:
            --priority <ServicePriority> | -p <ServicePriority>
            --raidset <RAIDSetName> | -r <RAIDSetName>
            --waitfortask | -W
NYCretoucher-Remote:~ nisian$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`$ sudo raidutil modify volume --expand -n R1V1 -s 100%`